# How to install and use beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to use BeautifulSoup on python3.4.3 (windows 7). I installed it with cmd.exe. But as I try to import it I get an error saying no module named `BeautifulSoup` or `BeautifulSoup4`.

Could you please help me? This is how I installed `beautifulsoup4`:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Did you even read throught the first example in the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) of the module you're about to use? Consider doing that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module is named `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Make sure you use the [correct documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for BeautifulSoup version 4, it lists details like these.

Yes, the project name (`beautifulsoup4`) differs from the module you import!